# I can't do a 'simple' onEdit function, app script is very new to me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am extremely new to Google app scripts and I am trying to convert a vba excel spreadsheet over.

Basically, I am first testing functions in a new simple spreadsheet, with the spreadsheet named **mycalculator**.

I would then like a user to edit to cell C4 which is named **distance**. and then with that cell change to then update the value in cell C6 which is named **conversion** with a value of **100**.

How do I do this exactly? Needless to say I have tried the code below and without success. Obviously I am trying to compile something from different sources that I have found, but I keep hitting brick walls.

Also, do I need to reference the spreadsheet? Can I not have the script tied to the one sheet only?

With VBA, I was easily able to follow online tutorials, with app script I am struggling to get started.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName(); 
  if(sheetName == 'mycalculator' && 'distance') { 
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      .getSheetByName('mycalculator').getRange('conversion').setValue(100);    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't just put a formula in C7 =IF(C4="","",100) but here is an onEdit that will do it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let sheet = e.range.getSheet()
    if( sheet.getName() === "mycalculator" ) {
      if( ( e.range.getRow() === 4 ) && ( e.range.getColumn() === 3 ) ) {  // cell C4
        sheet.getRange("conversion").setValue(100);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("onEdit() "+err);
  }
}
```

Here as an alternate solution if you really need to use the named range "distance".

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let sheet = e.range.getSheet()
    if( sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
      if( e.range.getA1Notation() === sheet.getRange("distance").getA1Notation() ) {  // cell C4
        sheet.getRange("conversion").setValue(100);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("onEdit() "+err);
  }
}
```

For your information there are numerous examples at these sites.

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Advance Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [javascript Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp)

Comment: Thank you, however, it isn't quite what I was after. I am hoping to use the reference to the named cell only. I.e "distance" instead of col and row reference numbers. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: You can not.  The event object `e` is the current cell as a Range.  There is a Range and there is a NamedRange.  You can get the Range from a NamedRange but not the other way around.  There is no `e.range.getName() === "distance"`

Comment: Can not? Is there another function other than using the event object for a range? If I can do this in my excel VBA workbook why can't I in Javascript? 

So, in other words, if I add a column or row, then my onEdit change event won't work anymore? Sorry, but I do find that hard to comprehend.